# How do I link to an external css style sheet using a Maven Java project using Spring

Tags: java, css, spring, eclipse, maven

I am trying to avoid inline styling and am having a hard time linking html pages to an external css style sheet for my Java Maven project in Eclipse. I am also using Spring framework. I have never had any issue with this before but am new to creating Maven projects, as well as new to using the Spring framework. Everywhere I look, it shows people using a webapp folder but I don't seem to have this in my project. Also, I am not currently using JSP, but just html pages. Can anyone please help me accomplish this?
My file structure where my html pages are is as follows:

```
>src/main/resources
>>templates
>>>start.html
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by hard time? Whats the issue. And by external css do you mean 1. locally in some other folder 2. https URL

Comment: Does it matter where I actually put it as long as I get the path correct to link to it?

Comment: I can't seem to figure out where to put this css file in order to link to it correctly. I have tried to put it in a css folder in the src/main/resources folder but it doesn't seem to link. Maybe my path is incorrect. When I did this, I used <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/myStyle.css" /> but this did not work. Also, I am trying to link locally to some other folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a  spring boot project then place it in resorces/static folder and
link it like this

```
<link href="/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

If it is a normal webproject then place it in web-inf or webapp folder then 
reference it directly in the same as above.

Comment: I have both the html pages and the css file in a templates folder within the resources folder and this is not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is not going to work. Change your maven build to move this files to WEB-INF folder during the war building.

Comment: I added a folder named static and it worked. Thanks for your help.